# Nutils 'Hello world!'

Tags: finite-element, nutils

Suppose I am completely new with the Python-based finite element package [Nutils](http://www.nutils.org), what example code would help me to get started?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Note that pure software questions are off-topic on this site -- in particular, this site should not be used as the support forum for your finite element package! (You should look at the discussions about the "FEniCS experiment" on meta to see why.)

Comment: It also looks quite suspicious if two of the lead developers of the software ask and answer their own questions in short succession... Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/documentation would be a better fit for what you seem to be trying to do here. You can also create your own Q&A forum, like FEniCS did: https://fenicsproject.org/qa/

Comment: Hi @ChristianClason, thanks for the feedback. Could you please comment on how this relates to the meta discussion "[let's define our scope](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2/lets-define-our-scope)", which we consulted prior to selecting this platform and which states "Questions about how to use a particular piece of software, either at a user interface (graphical or not) _or at a programming interface_, are scicomp"? [emphasis mine]

Comment: Indeed we did discuss whether SO would be the more appropriate platform, but given their hostility towards mathjax there would be no way to formulate any relevant question. And before we can use documentation (which does enable it) we need 500+ questions. With regard to your last comment: though it is of course true that we could have created our own Q&A forum, we assume that stackexchange provides their service with the objective that people make use of it.

Comment: @gertjan That question dates from the very beginning of the site, which has since evolved. More current meta discussions are http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/338/can-scicomp-stackexchange-be-used-for-project-specific-questions and http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/353/thoughts-comments-and-reactions-about-the-fenics-experiment. In the right context, software questions *are* on topic here, but what you're trying to do (seeding the site with tutorial-type questions) is not it. Such questions should arise out of *actual*, *scientific*, problems.

Comment: And to be perfectly honest, the fact that there's a commercial entity behind Nutils gives the whole thing a taste of spamming. (Not saying that that's what you're actually doing, but you should be aware of how it could look to an external observer.) In any case, asking on Meta first would have been the way to go.

Comment: @ChristianClason We were simply looking for a Q&A platform for our community and thought to be fully in scope. Seeding (three) tutorial questions was a way of experimenting with the platform and gaining required reputation to create the tag, after which we envisioned the community to take over. Should we expect the present [on hold] status to be permanent?

Comment: Even though I understand the ambivalence about software specific questions, the Nutils user base is predominantly academic and I am sure that drawing them to scicomp could benefit the platform (I consider this to be one of the benefits of a shared knowledge base such as stackexchange). Questions labeled 'nutils' will be largely implementational, however; if these are unwanted then we will no further push for a place here.

Comment: As I wrote, that was precisely what was tried with FEniCS, and the consensus was that this was not a good idea, for all parties involved. If you want to revisit this discussion (which you are welcome to do), you should ask a question on Meta (explaining the background of the project, what you hope to get out of it, and why concretely it would benefit this SE community) -- after all, I'm just a random guy on the internet and speak for no one except myself. Otherwise, the "on hold" status won't change unless the questions change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following fully functional script solves the Laplace problem for a scalar valued field $ u $, such that for all test functions $ v $:
$$ \int_\Omega ∇v·∇u = \int_{\Gamma_N} v f $$
where $\Omega$ is the unit square domain with a Neumann condition $ f = 1 $ on the right boundary $\Gamma_N$, a homogeneous Dirichlet condition $ u = 0 $ on the lower boundary, and natural boundary conditions on the remaining boundaries. The spaces are discretized using quadratic spline basis functions on an 8x8 computational grid.

```py
from nutils import mesh, function, plot

# prepare domain, geometry, basis
domain, geom = mesh.rectilinear( [range(9),range(9)] )
basis = domain.basis( 'spline', degree=2 )

# construct matrix, right hand side, constraints
matrix = domain.integrate( basis['i,k'] * basis['j,k'], geometry=geom, ischeme='gauss2' )
rhs = domain.boundary['right'].integrate( basis, geometry=geom, ischeme='gauss2' )
con = domain.boundary['bottom'].project( 0, onto=basis, geometry=geom, ischeme='gauss2' )

# solve system
lhs = matrix.solve( rhs, constrain=con )
sol = basis.dot( lhs )

# plot solution
points, colors = domain.elem_eval( [geom, sol], ischeme='bezier9', separate=True )
with plot.PyPlot( 'solution' ) as plt:
  plt.mesh( points, colors )
  plt.colorbar()
```

Running this code generates the following graph of the solution:

[image]

### Where to go from here?

A more elaborate getting started document can be found [here](https://joostvanzwieten.github.io/nutils-by-example/). Furthermore, the [examples](https://github.com/nutils/nutils/tree/master/examples) included in Nutils provide fully functional example code for a wide range of problems.